# Determine if dynamic selects are defined with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

I've stumbled across a problem and could use your help figuring out some logic here to deal with it. Basically I have a dynamic order form where the price is updated real time on the user side using javascript based on what options the user selects. The issue is that there are 3 dynamic dropdowns that might not all exist, ie sometimes there will be drop down a - c, sometimes there will only be a, or just a and b, etc. The error I'm getting is that the variable for any undefined select is undefined (obviously). I've implemented some js to deal with that but with no success. Here is the code I'm working with:

PHP:

```
     $a_sql = ("SELECT * FROM prod_add WHERE pid = '$id' AND `group` = 'a'");
$a_query = mysqli_query($dbconx, $a_sql);
$a_Count = mysqli_num_rows($a_query);
if ($a_Count > 0) {



    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($a_query)) {

    $a_option = $row["option"];
    $a_value = $row["value"];

    $a_results .= "<option value='$a_value'>$a_option</option>";

    }

}

if($a_Count > 0) {

    $a_opt = "<select class='opt_drop' id='optA' name='optA' onchange='getTotal()'>$a_results</select>"; 

} else { 

    $a_opt = "";

}
```

Rinse and repeat for b & c

HTML:

```
   <h2 id="totalPrice">$<?php echo $base_cost ?></h2> <br />
          <input type="hidden"  name="base_cost" id="base_cost" value="<?php echo $base_cost ?>" /> 
          <?php echo $a_opt; ?><br />
          <?php echo $b_opt; ?><br />
          <?php echo $c_opt; ?>
            Quantity:
          <select name="quantity" id="quantity" onchange="getTotal()">
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4</option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                <option value="10"> 10 </option>
          </select>
```

Javascript:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

     function getDDValue(elementID){
         var value = 0;
         var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
          value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
         console.log(value);
         return parseFloat(value);
     }
     function getBase (elementID) {
        var value = 0;
        var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
        value = element.value;
        return parseFloat(value);
     }

     function getTotal(){
         if (typeof optA != "undefined") {
         var optA =  getDDValue("optA");
        } else {
            var optA = "0";
        }
        if (typeof optB != "undefined") {
            var optB =  getDDValue("optB");
        } else {
            var optB = "0";
        }
        if (typeof optC != "undefined") {
              var optC =  getDDValue("optC");
          } else {
             var optC = "0";
          }
          var quantity = getDDValue("quantity");
        var base_cost = getBase ("base_cost")
          var totalPrice = '0';

         totalPrice = parseFloat((+base_cost  + +optA + +optB + +optC) * +quantity);
         console.log(totalPrice);
          document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "$" + totalPrice; 
     }

     getTotal();
     </script>
```

As you can see above I tried determining if the value was undefined and if it was to just give it a value of 0. That didn't work though I can't be sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `typeof` in javascript, it's generally a good idea to compare the results with a triple equals comparator So instead of using `!=` use `!==`

Also in javascript, if you pass an object whose value is `undefined` into a conditional statement it will evaluate to false. [If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)
This means that you could rewrite the above as follows unless you're specifically looking for the value to be exactly `undefined`:

```
function getTotal(){

    // If optA does not exist, create the variable and assign it 
    if (!optA) {
        var optA =  getDDValue("optA");
    // Otherwise it exists, now set it to "0" pleaseandthankyou :)
    } else {
        optA = "0";
    }

    ...

}
```

**EDIT :** Based on your replies to the above answer I think this might help: The variable `element` is null. That means that no elements could not be found with an id of `elementID` and so it was set to null. Because it is null, it has no property `options`. Check to make sure that there actually is a DOM element with the id attribute equal to whatever you pass in as `elementID`.

```
function getDDValue(elementID){
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var value;

    // if the element exists
    if(element){
        value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    }else{
        value = 0;
    }

    console.log(value);
    return parseFloat(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this informative response. Whether the value is null, undefined etc is not important, what is important is that if the admin has only uploaded 2 categories of selects (say A and B) that the javascript will overlook c since it does not exist. THe two examples (the code and the triple equals comparator) didn't work though I'm not sure why. I'm still getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null products.php?id=1:27
getDDValue products.php?id=1:27
getTotal products.php?id=1:54
(anonymous function)` in the javascript console.

Comment: also I think the logic is backwards in the code you posted, what i was trying to do is if it is defined then set the variable to the dynamic option selected, else if it is undefined the value is 0 since the equation in the back is basically `(base_cost + a + b + c) * quantity` though reversing it didn't work either.

Comment: Oops yeah that logic was backwards but as long as you get the concept. See my edit for what I think is happening with that TypeError

Answer (score 0):

`optA` (and also the others) in the `if` condition of `getTotal` will always be `undefined`. Js does only know function level scopes and it does not matter where in the function you have defined them using `var`  (you could also define them all at the end of you function body).

So all occurrence of `optA` are bound to the scope of the function. That's why it is always `undefined`.